# Deploying AjaxToolkit causes script reference error

Tags: ajax

My site running locally works OK. Once deployed to web server I get the following error:

A script reference cannot be included multiple times in composite script references.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A script reference cannot be included multiple times in composite script references.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: A script reference cannot be included multiple times in composite script references.]
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RemoveDuplicates(List`1 scripts) +669
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts() +376
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +113
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) +8698542
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1029

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3615; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3614
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I have a script manager in my master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the clue was in the error message. There was a master page already loadnig the ajax javascript.